# Connecting to an existing SQL database on cordova using angularjs/php back end

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, cordova

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) 
{
    $scope.initialize = function() {
        $http.get("/server/connect.php", {transformResponse: []})
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) 
    {
        console.log(data);
    })
    .error( function(data, status, headers, config) 
    {
        console.log("Error: " + data + "; " + status);
    });
    }
}]);

<?php
    //===================//
    // Set our time zone //
    //===================//
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

    $connectionInfo = array("UID"           =>'app',
                            "PWD"           =>'App123',
                            "Database"      =>'appdb',
                            "CharacterSet"  =>'UTF-8');

    $conn = sqlsrv_connect('app-server', $connectionInfo);

    if($conn)
    {
        echo "connected";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "connection failed";
    }
?>
```

**Edit:**

I now have managed to install xampp and php. The xamp is connecting to the apache server and php is running and I can access my localhost now. However, when I navigate to the php file where it's doing the connection I am getting

```
Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect()
```

I already have these in my php.ini, stop and started the apache server but still getting the same error.

```
extension="c:\xampp\php\ext\php_sqlsrv_53_ts.dll"
extension="c:\xampp\php\ext\php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_ts.dll"
extension="c:\xampp\php\ext\php_pdo.dll"
```

Comment: Generally you will use an angular service to GET/POST via an API you build on the back end. The API is what is connected to the database directly. You can also use scripts to do this, which is not my personal preference, but some examples are here: https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_sql.asp

Comment: You need a backend service that can interact with database. A client app can't do this

Comment: updated the question

Comment: OK, good - So now, were you able to connect to the database from PHP? Did you create a table and tried inserting data from php using INSERT query?

Comment: This is what I am trying to check. I'm outputting the data variable onto the console to check if it has connected or not. Surely, if it echo'd either "connected" or "connection failed" on the php file, it would output either string on the console but it's outputting the whole php code instead.

Comment: I also already have existing tables and data within my database.

Comment: @J.Do OH! So you haven't installed a web server on your localhost (i.e - Your computer)! You can download and install Apache web server  from here https://httpd.apache.org/ Then you need to install PHP, and only then you can move on :)

Comment: @J.Do Here is a relevant tutorial that might help you https://www.znetlive.com/blog/how-to-install-apache-php-and-mysql-on-windows-10-machine/

Comment: @AlonEitan I'll give this a go thank you!

Comment: @AlonEitan I've managed to install apache and PHP but I am currently getting `Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect()`. I've installed the sqlsrv extensions to the folder but still not working.

Comment: @J.Do You probably didn't enable it on `php.ini` - Please [read this](http://php.net/manual/en/sqlsrv.installation.php), and you need to restart apache web server after you changed php.ini

Comment: @AlonEitan Not sure what i'm missing. I've already done the what it says on the page from the link you have provided.

Comment: @J.Do Sorry, don't know the reason then. Try Googling the error and I'm sure you'll find something helpful. I myself using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.installation.php) and prepared statement because it's safe against sql injections (If you use it correctly, with [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php))